# Failed Install Marlowe-CLI

Tags: marlowe

I cloned marlowe-cli from https://github.com/input-output-hk/marlowe-cardano/tree/cli-blog-april2022/marlowe-cli into WSL at /home/{user}
and attempted to install with the command:
`cabal install exe:marlowe-cli`
The install failed with the following message:
Failed to build lzma-0.0.0.3. The failure occurred during the configure step.
Build log (
/home/johnshearing/.cabal/logs/ghc-8.10.7/lzma-0.0.0.3-b8e5e5271afb9de54972ab2bbbbfe6e55609cefdde55c24b9e9d56d7e4cf3ba8.log
):
Configuring library for lzma-0.0.0.3..
cabal-3.6.2.0: Missing dependency on a foreign library:

- Missing (or bad) header file: lzma.h
- Missing (or bad) C library: lzma
  This problem can usually be solved by installing the system package that
  provides this library (you may need the "-dev" version). If the library is
  already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the flags
  --extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where it is.If the
  library file does exist, it may contain errors that are caught by the C
  compiler at the preprocessing stage. In this case you can re-run configure
  with the verbosity flag -v3 to see the error messages.
  If the header file does exist, it may contain errors that are caught by the C
  compiler at the preprocessing stage. In this case you can re-run configure
  with the verbosity flag -v3 to see the error messages.

cabal: Failed to build lzma-0.0.0.3 (which is required by exe:marlowe-cli from
marlowe-cli-0.0.4.0). See the build log above for details.

Can someone please tell me what to do?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what OS are you on?
on debian-based distros try installing

```
sudo apt install liblzma-dev
```

lzma.h is included in liblzma-dev, so this should solve the missing dependency.

as per

[this package search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=lzma.h&mode=exactfilename&suite=jammy&arch=any)

Comment: Thanks @Dark345. I am using WSL/Ubuntu I see by your package search link that Ubuntu is Debian Based. I will try your solution. and report back.

Comment: yep, let me know, thanks

Comment: Yes @Dark354, I ran the install for liblzma-dev and then cabal install for marlowe-cli and it went through without any errors. Much thanks

Comment: okay, perfect, you can mark as answered if you have time. Thanks